# Helping someone climb

Tags: single-word-requests

I know this is kinda stupid but what is the word for "helping someone climb by allowing him to stand on your hands" (to allow him/her see above some wall or climb something)?

Comment: More details: it usually implies clenching both your hands to allow someone put his foot on.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single English word for it; I know we have one for it in Slovenian. And Google Translate doesn't know how to translate the said word, which is more evidence from my end that such a word does not exist in English.

Comment: …so what is the word for it in Slovenian?  I know this isn’t slovenian.stackexchange.com, but now that you’ve mentioned it, I can’t help being curious!

Comment: @PLL: while you're waiting, I'll try to keep you entertained by presenting you with the German word: *Räuberleiter* ("looters' ladder"). It even has an [article on the German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Räuberleiter).

Comment: Our word "ravbarska" is actually derived from Räuberleiter, or rather, "ravbar" comes from the German word for thief Räuber and -ska makes it an adjective, then common usage makes it a nounified adjective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per Wiktionary, the word you are searching for is [*to give so. a leg up*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leg_up).

> Leg up: the act of assisting another's progress over a wall or other obstacle by forming a step for one of their feet with one's hands

Answer (score 12):

To boost or give someone a boost may work well, depending on how formal the context.

At least in American English, giving someone a leg up often is used in a more metaphorical sense, as in giving someone an advantage of some kind which is not necessary physical, so this phrase may confuse some readers if you are actually referring to the physical act of lifting someone up.

Comment: “To (give someone a) boost” also gets used figuratively.  I wouldn’t have thought it would be clearer?

Comment: Indeed, in the UK, I would not understand "give someone a boost" as having this literal meaning.

Comment: Indeed, in the US, I would not necessarily understand "give someone a boost" as having this literal meaning, though that is certainly one of its possible uses.

Comment: Yes, I also agree the "boost" has the metaphorical meaning. However, I would never use "a leg up" in the physical sense--to me, it only has a metaphorical meaning, while "boost" for me has both.

Answer (score 4):

I will throw in *[bunk-up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bunk-up)* for good measure, the complete expression being *to give someone a bunk-up*. I have only ever heard it in a movie or two. Wiktionary marks it as *UK*, perhaps someone from the US can comment on whether it would be understood there as well.

Comment: When I hear bunk up, I think sleep in the same room. This would be used for times when there are multiple beds in the room (hotel rooms, vacation homes, etc.) to describe who should share which rooms. It does not necessarily imply sharing the bed. I would say this phrase is used quite informally in the American English context.

Comment: I don't recognise "bunk-up" in the context of the question. (UK reader)

Answer (score 4):

In N.E. England, we always used the term ***["bunk up"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bunk-up)***.

> Give me a bunk up so I can get the ball back.

Searching the web, this now seems to have sexual connotations in some contexts though.

I've also heard "leg up" & "boost".

Comment: _Leg-up_ is what I would instinctively say, possibly through AmE influence (?). I don't recall hearing _bunk-up_ from AmE speakers, at least, so I'd suspect there may be a dialectal difference here.

Answer (score 1):

"Hey Felix, could you **give me a boost**?"

When uttered in front a wall or tree, this will normally produce the *hand-clasping* you describe. The *hand-clasping technique* is not the only way to boost someone, but it certainly seems the default in this situation. That said, as someone gains a handhold and manages to haul themselves up a reasonable way but still lacks a foothold, we sometimes shift to the awkward *bum-push technique*.

> **boost** (noun): an upward thrust or push (He gave him a boost over the wall.)

Also used as a very, as in:

"Hey Felix, can you **boost** me up?"

> **boost** (transitive verb): to raise or lift by pushing up from below (He boosted me over the wall.)

[image]

Definitions from *www.thefreedictionary.com.*

Answer (score 1):

"Could you give me a leg up" is used not only for help getting on a horse, but over a fence, or to any higher elevation.

"Give me a boost" is not used in the horse situation, except by people extremely ignorant of the term *leg up*, which, by the way, is used from Texas to Canada.

In AmE, at least, *bunk up* means to sleep in the same bed, as in "who are ya gonna bunk up with?" I am unfamiliar with its English usage to mean *boost*.

So, in short, "give me a boost" would be the most common phrase. In AmE to answer the OPs actual question.

Comment: Your conclusion kind of contradicts your first two paragraphs… (And of your comment about New England was related to Ste’s answer, note that he wrote N.E. England, i.e., northeastern England.)